# Memory Mapping Table

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, memory, decoder, nand

I am a begginer in the field of microcomputers and their architecture and recently I got an assignment with the following instructions:

> With the use of the mapping table find out which adresses in IC2, IC3 and IC4 circuits occupy the system address space. In case of incomplete decoder list all address blocks in which the circuits are mirrored.

If I understood corectly, the system data bus has 8 bits - **AD [0..7]**, and all of the mentioned ICs (IC2-4) has 8 bits on local data bus. If I'm correct, that means I can use 1:1 mapping. I made a table where I mapped the IC2 and IC3. On these two ICs the **Chip Select pins are A15**, so I could use logic 0 and 1 for selecting them.

| A15 | A14 | A13 | A12 | A11 | A10 | A9 | A8 | A7 | A6 | A5 | A4 | A3 | A2 | A1 | A0 | System Address Bus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **A14** | **A13** | **A12** | **A11** | **A10** | **A9** | **A8** | **A7** | **A6** | **A5** | **A4** | **A3** | **A2** | **A1** | **A0** | **IC2 Local Address Bus** |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | <0000H |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7FFFF> |
|  | **A14** | **A13** | **A12** | **A11** | **A10** | **A9** | **A8** | **A7** | **A6** | **A5** | **A4** | **A3** | **A2** | **A1** | **A0** | **IC3 Local Address Bus** |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | <8000H |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | FFFFF> |

I am pretty sure that I missed something, because now I can not map the IC4. Also there are the WR#, RD# and PSEN# signals and 3 NAND gates below the 3 ICS, which have something to do with the IC4, but I do not know what.

Can someone please help to navigate me, what should I do?

Here is the scheme and the mentioned ICs are in the yellow-red square in the right part of the picture.

[image: Scheme]

Comment: Just write out truth tables for the logic gates to see which memory chip is reacting to which signals. It also looks like you assume the 8051 has a single 64kB memory space but it doesn't, so I recommend reading how 8051 external buses work.

Comment: This map table should include all signals RD, WR, PSEN, ALE, ... and not only A15..A0. There is 3 IC which have 32k x 8 memory. Where are they ?

Comment: Something as this ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/71kdu.png

Comment: Please note that parallel buses and external memories like these is a very old design. Modern professional applications will as long as possible keep memories on-chip, or otherwise utilize serial buses, which are generally far more robust in terms of EMI and error detection.

Comment: Very old design, yes, but that can explain why and how, there is, for example, a "memory space" and a "IO space" ...

Comment: @Antonio51 Thanks for the demonstration, but how will I found out the memory spaces of ICs. Are there 20 bits to work with (16+4 control) or only A15..0 pins (16bits). I am confused

Comment: These are all good hints at solving your homework problem. I would add that you review briefly the AT89S52 chip datasheet (can find one here: https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/xzrqsynxrv/ATMLS04877-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw) and review the descriptions of those pins involved (such as RD#, WR#, and PSEN#) with the memory chips (IC2, IC3, IC4). Next, do the same for the memory chips and pins WE\, OE\, and CS\. This should help you construct the memory map table.

Comment: The "control" added bits may be considered as "addresses", although there are not so.

Comment: Read for example, paragraph 6, page 10, about memory organization for AT89S52 (above link). You can see that some instruction knows what data to use and where ... See also this :  https://www.electronicshub.org/8051-microcontroller-memory-organization/  https://annamalaiuniversity.ac.in/studport/download/engg/csd/resources/8051%20Memory%20Organization.pdf